# I need to perform some action as soon as we press back key when progressDailog is in progress

Tags: android, progressdialog

I use progressDailog to compute my data.. But when i press backKey then this progressDailog disappears but computation of data carry on in background... I need to stop this Computation... As obviously when user presses this back key then he doesnt want this computation of data... Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an [OnCancelListene](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29)r and stop the computations there.